# php-fpm error on EC2 : the process manager is missing (static, dynamic or ondemand)

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, php

I am trying to install nginx on Amazon EC2. The nginx part is running fine. But I am getting problem with php-fpm. When I run service php-fpm start I got error: php-fpm on EC2 Error : the process manager is missing (static, dynamic or ondemand). I was following this tutorial: http://codingsteps.com/install-php-fpm-nginx-mysql-on-ec2-with-amazon-linux-ami/ . I am not sure why I am getting this error. Can someone help me with installing php-fpm.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add the pm option to your config file. For example using ondemand process management:

```
[example.com]
user = example
group = example
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm/example/sock
listen.owner = example
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 770
chdir = /srv/www/wp-content/example/
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 4
```